# Custom Thumbnails with Nivo Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nivo-slider

I need to use text links instead of image links for Nivo Slider thumbnails, and I need to display them in a completely arbitrary location. Is there an easy way to to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just wrote a bit of custom script, pretty proud of its simplicity.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".custom-control").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var targetSlide = $(this).attr("rel");
        $(".slider-wrapper .nivoSlider .nivo-controlNav").find(".nivo-control").attr("rel", targetSlide).trigger("click");
    });
});
```